# Printing from Sierra to a shared printer on Windows 10

Tags: windows, printing

I want to print to a printer attached to a Windows 10 machine. I tried setting up a workgroup then selecting the Windows tab for adding a printer, but this does not seem to work. It can submit a job to the print queue and I can see it on my Windows 10 machine, but it immediately disappears. Is there another method that I can use instead?

Comment: Does printing in general work on the Window 10 machine - in other words, can you print a test document from Windows?

Comment: @Allan Yes I can print on the Windows machine

Comment: Enable logging for the printer and see what's happening - instructions can be found here:    https://superuser.com/questions/959751/windows-10-enable-logging-for-printing